# Is it possible to change the size of the CAP_SQUARE?

Tags: java, graphics

[image: hexagon with midpoints joined]

In the attached picture, I am trying to join the midpoints of a hexagon with a thick line. As you can see, the line is not long enough. Is there a way to set the size of CAP_SQUARE (as you can with the MITRE) to make it longer?

I know I can compute points outside the hexagon and join them instead to do this, but I need to draw a large number of points, and it becomes too complex.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the CAP_SQUARE will not help.

The triangle to be filled is:

- mid point 60°, edge with length 2L,
- point on hexagon 30°, edge with length sqrt(3).L,
- point 90° edge with length L.

Hence the mid points connecting line has at each end must be lengthened by

```
(sqrt(3) - 1)*L
```

where L is half the line thickness.

Comment: Thanks. That did it!